# problem in pass php array to js function contain space in array items

Tags: javascript, php, json, encode

i pass a php array to js function. but array items contain space. for example for name="Ali alavi".
when i use `encode_json($value)` to pass js function , i got error: (if my items contain space get this)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break
```

this error appear only on pass encoded to js func.

my php code:(`$value` is array contain U_name,U_family,U_username,U_role)

```
 $db = Db::getInstance();
$sql = "select * from users ";
$record = $db->query($sql);
$i = 1;
foreach ($record as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr><td><a onclick=editRecord('" . json_encode($value) . "') data-toggle='modal' data-target='#userModal' href='#'><i class='icon-pencil'></i><a></td></tr>";
}
```

my js func:

```
 function editRecord(n) {
        let p = JSON.parse(n);
        console.log(p['U_name']);}
```

Comment: Check to see what the php output is (ie check view source in browser).  Check for unescaped line breaks but also for single quotes which break those around the editRecord param.

Comment: i got ```ali%20alavi```

Comment: i got this error on only pass encoded object to js func

Comment: Please share more details about the debugging trace, which line of your code is causing the error? What is the backtrace?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try searching before posting a new question, if you search for your error messge you will find many other questions here about it, with many answers, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59625312/syntaxerror-string-literal-contains-an-unescaped-line-break, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the source code in the browser, the HTML is probably not valid. I assume this is a JavaScript error from the console?

Something like `onclick=editRecord('...')` might work, but it's better to add quotes around the value like this `onclick="editRecord('...')"`. This is probably what's causing the issue, because there is a space in the value.

If you do add the quotes, there is an issue with the JSON which will also contain quotes. Something like this `onclick="editRecord('{"name":"value"}')"`, which is also not valid.

If you replace the double quotes with `&quot;` it will work, but you might also have other special characters in the JSON, so something like `htmlspecialchars` will work better. Like this:

```
$db = Db::getInstance();
$sql = "select * from users ";
$record = $db->query($sql);
$i = 1;
foreach ($record as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr><td><a onclick=\"editRecord('" . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($value)) . "')\" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#userModal' href='#'><i class='icon-pencil'></i><a></td></tr>";
}
```